# How are SQL Transactions and JavaScript Promises related?

Tags: javascript, sql, asynchronous, transactions, promise

I recently learned about [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A), which seemed similar to SQL Transactions.

- Transactions are all or nothing
- Promises are sequential callbacks

  Are they different implementations of the same concept to handle asynchronous events?

Comment: [Example of Transactions + Promises + ES6 generators together](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises are a general concept dealing with asynchronousness. Transactions are a means to guarantee atomicity when updating multiple records.

They might appear together in some library but they are not related. You could see them together if you have a transactional database that has an asynchronous API.

Comment: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is one such example, see [transaction examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions).

Answer (score 1):

**Intent:**

A promise provides a high-level interface for synchronizing asynchronous callbacks

A transaction provides a high-level interface for executing dependent SQL statements

**Use Case**

When an application needs a future value, it constructs the promise on demand and waits until it has returned.

When a database needs to peform a series of data manipulations, a transaction is constructed

**Error Handling**

If a promise raises an exception, the exception is returned and the future is suspended

If a transaction raises an exception, a rollback is executed on the pending transaction

**Mutation**

If there are no exceptions, the computed value is returned in the future object.

If there are no exceptions, the final result set of the transaction is committed

**Side-Effects**

In a transaction block, you can write queries to more than one database, but you must commit or roll back a transaction to one database before writing a query to another.

In a future, you can assign values to one or more global or non-local variables; there is no commit or rollback

**Tainting**

A read can occur during the execution of concurrent SQL transactions. The possible read actions include:

- dirty read, in which a second SQL transaction reads a row before the first SQL transaction executes a COMMIT
- non-repeatable read, in which a SQL transaction reads a row and then a second SQL transaction modifies or deletes the row and executes a COMMIT;
- phantom, in which a SQL transaction reads rows that meet search criteria, a second SQL transaction then generates at least one row that meets the first transaction's search criteria, and then the first transaction repeats the search, resulting in a different result set.

An assignment or serialization can occur during the execution of a future without warning

**State Management**

Setting savepoints lets you roll back portions of a transaction. For example, if your transaction includes an insert, an update, and a delete, and you set a savepoint after the update, you can roll back the transaction to exclude the delete.

A future has no savepoints

**References**

> [cftransaction](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cftransaction)
>  
>  [Understanding the Available Transaction Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546518.aspx)
>  
>  [Asynchronous Programming in JavaScript with Promises](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx)
>  
>  [How Transactional Replication Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179423)
>  
>  [Transaction Process Synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977035.aspx)
>  
>  [Optimistic Algorithm](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs5204/fall99/distributedDBMS/wen/notes.html)
>  
>  [Concurrency Control Algorithms](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-classic/concurrency-control-algorithms.html)
>  
>  [Configuring Serializable Isolation](http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/docs/je/1.7.1/GettingStartedGuide/serializable.html)
>  
>  [Improving concurrency with new registry variables](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509schuetz/)
>  
>  [Operating Systems Lecture Notes: Allocation and Deadlock](http://bluehawk.monmouth.edu/~rclayton/web-pages/s12-os/resourcemgt.html)
>  
>  [SQLite File I/O Specification](http://www.sqlite.org/fileio.html)
>  
>  [Broken promises–C++0x futures](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2009/03/03/broken-promises-c0x-futures/) 
>  
>  [concurrent.futures — Launching parallel tasks](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html)
>  
>  [Javascript Is Awesome: I don't want promises](http://javascriptisawesome.blogspot.com/2012/12/i-dont-want-promises.html)
>  
>  [JavaScript Asynchronous Architectures: Events vs. Promises](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-asynchronous-architectures-events-vs-promises/)
>  
>  [AS3 Promises - a guide and example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/AS3+Promises+-+a+guide+and+example)
>  
>  [Smalltalk Concurrency, Playing With Futures](http://onsmalltalk.com/smalltalk-concurrency-playing-with-futures)
>  
>  [promise-streams](https://github.com/spion/promise-streams)
>  
>  [System.Threading.TTask.Future](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Threading.TTask.Future#Description)
>  
>  [Promises Part 5: The Lego Problem](http://blog.getify.com/promises-part-5/)
>  
>  [Callbacks vs Events](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2009/03/callbacks-vs-events/)
>  
>  [Events and Callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229041)
>  
>  [Events vs. Callbacks – when to use what](http://www.ghost23.de/2010/10/events-vs-callbacks-when-to-use-which/)
>  
>  [coroutines,callbacks,message-queues - Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/38429)
>  
>  [Introduction to ES6 Promises – The Four Functions You Need To Avoid Callback Hell](http://jamesknelson.com/grokking-es6-promises-the-four-functions-you-need-to-avoid-callback-hell/)
>  
>  [All about ES6 Generators](http://blog.getify.com/all-about-es6-generators/)
>  
>  [Chaining Difference in ES6 Promisies and PEP3148 Futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767593/chaining-difference-in-es6-promises-and-pep3148-futures)

Comment: That "References" section is way too big. Should each of those links prove one statement? Then use footnotes.